# How do I get message_reads webhook from Facebook?

Tags: facebook-webhooks

I have an issue with message_reads webhook (Messenger Conversations). I have been registered my app to messages and message_reads webhooks but I only get events from messages.

My app has pages_messaging advanced access and it's in live mode. So I can get messages from anyone, but no notification about reading.

What I'm doing wrong?